# C fgets not getting full text

Tags: c, char, fgets

When I use this code

```
char *openFile(const char file[1024]){
FILE *f = fopen(file, "r");
char c[1000];
char *d;
if (f!=NULL) {
    if (fgets(c, 1000, f) !=NULL){
        d = c;
    }
    else{
        d = "No text";
    }
}
else{
    d="error";
    printf("%s", d);
}
fclose(f);

return d;
}
```

to get, for example, text that is this long

```
fosndjfnsondfnsnkdfsjndfoweoingfoweljksdnflwkengdfwoensldkfwejlnfkdlskdfnlskdnflskdnflksndlfknslkdnflkndlknfslnlfjnlksdnjfnjwnejnfwenfnjwenlfodnakdoifnkleroglknerolkdfgnrkldsfgnlskdfgnlksdfglndlfkngkldnslkgnlkfdnkglnklsndfklnglfdlskgknllkdglksdfkkngkresoirigknlsdf
```

(This text doesn't mean anything, it's just a test) and I return the `char *d;` it outputs this

```
fosndjfnsondfnsnkdfsjndfoweoingfoweljksdnflwkengdfwoensldkfwejlnfkdlskdfnlskdnflskdnflksndlfknslkdnflkndlknfslnlfjnlksdnjfnjwnejnfwenfnjwenlfodnakdoifnkleroglknerolkdfgnrkldsfgnlskdfgnlksdfglndlfkngkldnslkgnlkfdnkglnklsndfklnglfdlskgknllkdglksdfkkngkresoir¯ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇv”[
```

Why are there those strange characters at the end?

Comment: When `fgets` succeeds, you're returning a pointer to a local variable. That ceases to exist when the function returns, so you return a dangling pointer.

Comment: Most modern compilers will warn you about returning a pointer to a local  variable like this.

Comment: I'm using Xcode, so I'm actually surprised it didn't. It usually warns me about everything.

Comment: Actually - I see why, the compiler's missing it because you're not returning the array pointer itself, but another pointer that's been assigned to the local array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined `c` as a local variable in `openFile`. Assuming your read succeeds, you're returning its address in `d`. It's destroyed at the end of `openFile`, so `d` becomes a dangling pointer. Attempting to use it after `openFile` returns results in undefined behavior.

Possible cures include defining `c` as `static`, and returning a buffer allocated with `malloc` instead. Defining `c` as `static` has a fair number of pitfalls, especially when/if multi-threading gets involved, so dynamic allocation is often quite a bit cleaner.